# How to generalize a class inheriting from another class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class that looks like:

```
public class InvokeProxy : MarshalRefByObject, IFace
{
    public InvokeProxy(IFace face)
    {
        this.Face = face;
    }

    private IFace Face { get; set; }

    public string Execute(string data)
    {
        return this.Face.Execute(data)
    }
}
```

And I'm tasked with making it generic. Since I can't inherit from the generic class, I'm somewhat stuck, does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: What part of the class are you expected to make generic?

Comment: @cadrell0 I'm supposed to make the InvokeProxy class generic.

Comment: by generic you mean InvokeProxy<T> generic? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're looking to do by making `InvokeProxy` into `InvokeProxy<T>`...does this help?

```
public class InvokeProxy<T> : MarshalRefByObject, IFace where T : IFace
{
    public InvokeProxy(T face)
    {
        this.Face = face;
    }

    private T Face { get; set; }

    public string Execute(string data)
    {
        return this.Face.Execute(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, here's something to get you started: that's called constraints on generic type parameters.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if I understood the question....

```
public class InvokeProxy<T> : MarshalRefByObject where T : class
{
    public InvokeProxy(T face)
    {
        this.Face = face;
    }

    private T Face { get; set; }

    public string Execute(string data)
    {
        return this.Face.Execute(data)
    }
}
```